# AutoCompleteDecorator with combo box

Tags: java, swing, autocomplete, jcombobox, swingx

I have a `JComboBox` with list of 200 task names. Initial selection is blank in the `JComboBox`.

```
    JComboBox combo = new JComboBox();
    combo.setEditable(false);
    combo.addItem("");
    for (MyTask task : this.tasks) {
        combo.addItem(task.getTaskName());
    }
    combo.setSelectedIndex(0);
    combo.addActionListener(this);
    AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(combo);
```

Based on the task selected, a new `JFrame` pops up with a graph drawn based on the selection.

This happens in the `actionPerformed` method.

```
 JComboBox jcmbType = (JComboBox) evt.getSource();
 String selectedJob = (String) jcmbType.getSelectedItem();
 // code for JFrame popup with graph here
```

Since the number of tasks are huge, I have used `AutoCompleteDecorator` of `SwingX` api to facilitate selection of appropriate task.

However, as soon as I type the first letter, the first task starting with that letter gets selected and the `JFrame` pops up with its graph.

How to control this? I do not want anything to happen until user selects the task he wants.

If I add a `JButton` near the `JComboBox`, how can I read the `JComboBox`'s value in `JButton` action listener ?

Comment: nobody knows which of methods implemented in SwingX API(s) to initialize yours whatever task

Comment: If I add a JButton near the JComboBox, how can I read the JComboBox's value in JButton action listener ? == Oracle tutorials how to use Item/ActionListeners, better is Swing Action

Comment: use ListSelectionListener added to derived JList from JComboBox in the case that you want to listening of Key/Mouse Event, the changes until BasicComboBoxPopup is visible

Answer (score 0):

This is how the AutoCompleteDecorator works. It (pre-)selects the Item you are trying to enter.
Since you added an ActionListener, this will be invoked (when item is pre-select)

You can try to do following:

- remove the Action-Listener
- add Key-Listener (Listener may react on ENTER)